# Update Aptana to 3.3.0.201212131616-13122012161933 has hidden all my connections?

Tags: aptana

I´ve updated Aptana Studio 3 to version 3.3.0.201212131616-13122012161933 and no longer have success to my connections.
Where can I find them and recover?

I'm using Aptana as standalone, not as eclipse plugin.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Hi, no error messages. In the project explorer all projects are displayed, but the assigned connections are all gone.
Looks like a new Project has been created...

Comment: well, thanks for sharing. I will stay with aptana 3.2.

Comment: Yes, definitely stay with 3.2 - see below, this problem is even worse than Arne initially thought: not only does Aptana now forget the connections when you update, but every single time it's exited the connections are cleared as well...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, a new problem results.
I´ve manually retyped all my Connections, so that I did my works yesterday.

But today I started Aptana Studio and all my Connections are gone again!
They are choosable again in the Connection Manager, but after another restart, they are gone again.

Is there a property which I have to enable or disable to keep aptana the connections right to the projects?

thanks

**EDIT**
I´ve demonstrated my problem by images, because it´s easier to understand as my bad english.

**First**
I deinstalled Aptana and reinstalled it.
I began to create a new Project and for example three connections for it.

**Second**
I tested the Connections of functionality and all three are ok!
Then I closed Aptana Studio and resarted it.
No Connection is linked to the Project!
You can see step 1 and 2 [here](http://www.dp-one.net/aptana-problems/step-1.jpg)

**Third**
If I click the "+"-Symbol for a new Connection linked to the project, I can choose the manually added connections from the dropdown list and link it to the project.
See it on last screen [here](http://www.dp-one.net/aptana-problems/add-connection.jpg)

**My conjecture**
There must be something to disable or enable to keep the connections linked to the project.
But I don´t know what is my mistake. I handle the studio like in version 3.2.
Is there something changed in 3.3 what I don´t see?

Thanks for help

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.  Prior to this latest update, I had no problems with connections - but now, every time I quit Aptana (standalone), all of the connections are lost and must be manually re-added.  It's incredibly annoying, because some of my dev requires me to reboot frequently - and every single time I have to re-add every connection.

Comment: Until it's addressed, is there some way to get back to a previous version in which this bug didn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Today, appcelerator has published an update wich is able to fix the problem.
So you can fix it by starting Aptana Studio and run updates. After installation, all connections should be linked to their project as assigned by you!