# Updating Aptana hides all my Connections again

Tags: aptana, updates, connection

I updated my Aptana Studio (standalone, no eclipse plugin) and get lost again of all my connections.
Same problem as a year ago: [Update Aptana to 3.3.0.201212131616-13122012161933 has hidden all my connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891037/update-aptana-to-3-3-0-201212131616-13122012161933-has-hidden-all-my-connections)

It's very annoying when I want to develop something and think "ok, there is an update, lets do it quickly and work with the latest version", but after updating there is no background for developing because all the connections get lost.

Has anybody a solution for this problem?!
Thanks for help.
Arne

EDIT: actually updated version is 3.5.0.201401092130

ps: I love working with Aptana and respect the work of the developers, but these bugs are very annoying...

Answer (score 2):

I Had this issue as well, and found the answer in another thread. Simply change the Project nature of the project to "Web", make sure nothing else is checked and the connections will show. It worked for me.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the answer. In project properties I found the project nature under item "content assist". But the select box is disabled so I can't change to anything?! Is there another way to change the project nature?

Comment: If you right-click on the project in project explorer and go to properties, a new menu comes up. Highlight project nature, and make sure web is the only think checked. If you did it right, it'll change to web-primary.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem after upgrade to 3.5 :)
i tried change Project Nature to Web then Connection show again. thank Justin Lindsay!

but i think that solution isn't good and this is bug of Aptana :D